# Resultado NaN en javascript haciendo una calculadora basica

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando una calculadora basica pero esta vez con javascript y me arroja un resultado `NaN`

Estoy comenzando con javascript y no entiendo mucho el porque, este serie mi codigo:

```js
function suma() {
  var n1 = Number(document.getElementById('n1').value);
  var n2 = Number(document.getElementById('n2').value);
  var total = (n1 + n2);

  document.getElementById('total').value = total;

}
```

```html
<h2>Calculadora básica</h2>
<div>
  <label for="p1">Numero 1:</label>
  <input type="text" id='n1' placeholder="numero 1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="p2">Numero 2:</label>
  <input type="text" id='n2' placeholder="numero 2">
</div>
<br><br>

<input type="button" value="suma" onClick="suma()">
<br>
<p>TOTAL:<input type="text" id="total"></p>
<div id='error'></div>

<!-- Equi llamo a mi codigo JS -->
<script src="libreria.js"></script>
```

Comment: Es extraño, tu código funciona correctamente en el snippet...

Comment: Cuando el _input_ tiene caracteres no numéricos puedes forzar un cero por defecto en lugar de _NaN_ (o cualquier otro valor "falsy") con: `var n1 = Number(document.getElementById('n1').value) || 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código funciona correctamente, puede ser que tu problema sea debido a una copia antigua en caché de tu archivo .js en donde quizás tu función suma() era distinta a la versión actual.

Podrías ingresar al sitio, presionar **ctrl + shift + r** para para recargar la página y limpiar su caché, de esta forma se descargaría la última versión de tu archivo javascript e intentar de nuevo.

Comment: Excelente, acertaste, mi problema esta solucionado! muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro mucho, es un problema usual que puede darse también con archivos css así que tenelo presente, no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta para que les pueda ser de utilidad a la comunidad. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo esta funcionando correctamente miralo aqui abajo, verifica tu linea `<script src="libreria.js"></script>`
talvez no estas llamando al mismo archivo

```js
function suma(){
  var n1 = Number(document.getElementById('n1').value);
  var n2 = Number(document.getElementById('n2').value);
  var total = (n1 + n2);
  
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;

}
```

```html
<h2>Calculadora básica</h2>
<div>
    <label for="p1">Numero 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id = 'n1' placeholder="numero 1">
</div> 
<div>
    <label for="p2">Numero 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id = 'n2' placeholder="numero 2">
</div>  
<br><br>
 
 <input type="button" value="suma" onClick="suma()">
<br>
<p>TOTAL:<input type="text" id="total"></p>
<div id = 'error'></div>
```

Comment: verifique y sí estoy llamando al mismo pero aún sigue dandome resultado NaN :/

Comment: Entonces a tu archivo libreria.js agregale
$( document ).ready(function() {
// aqui tu funcion javascript
});
he intenta nuevamente

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin el OP no puso como etiqueta `JQuery` por lo cual se asume que no lo esta utilizando

Comment: El equivalente a `$( document ).ready(function() { // aqui tu funcion javascript });` sería `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { /* Código JS */ });`

Comment: @JuanRivera, pero el problema esta en su archivo.js porque en snippet funciona correctamente, por eso le menciono que revise su archivo ubicación tambien ahi tiene el problema, si no, que pase su funcion a la pagina principal

Comment: @anythingg correcto, seria mejor utilizar eso

Comment: Lo coloque así tal cua:l document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
function suma(){
  var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value);
  var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value);
  var total = (n1 + n2);
  
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
}); pero sigue el mismo error, y no puedo pasar el codigo JS a la pagina principal porque se me pide que se haga en un archivo externo

Comment: Replique lo que indicas tu funcion a un archivo externo y si me funciona la calculadora, porque no le das 'inspeccionar elemento' te vas a consola y le das click al boton suma, ahi debe decir si el archivo es el que no lo localiza, porque a mi me funciono con un archivo externo

https://takeafile.com/?f=beferujati , estos son los archivos que cree y funcionan bien

Comment: en el boton suma no me sale mas nada que NaN en el input text pero agregue otros botones cada uno de resta division y multiplicacion y revise en errores de consola y me arroja lo siguiente : Uncaught ReferenceError: division is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:48) OJO: todos menos el de suma me dan ese error, el de suma como ya mencione solo arroja NaN